# Encrypted Time Machine Backup to an Encrypted .sparsebundle Disk Image?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine, encryption

so I have this idea of mounting an Azure File Share in macOS

then create a .sparsebundle Disk Image with the Azure File Share to use it as my Time Machine backup disk.

I have multiple questions to understand the validate the approach

- Does it make sense to create an encrypted .sparsebundle Disk Image on the mounted Azure File Share and then mount the .sparsebundle and create encrypted Time Machine Backups on top? (two encryption layers)
- if one encryption layer is enough, which one I should choose? .sparsebundle or Time Machine?
- Ignore the creation of the .sparsebundle, and create encrypted Time Machine Backup directly on the mounted Azure File Share?

**Easy backup and restore with high security are important, so how to achieve a balanced approach?**